# Hard disk stop detecting temporarily yesterday, and now permanently

Tags: hard-drive, laptop, sata

My internal hard disk is 4 year old, and is only used for personal use.

Yesterday out of nowhere, it stopped detecting. I stopped my laptop, open the back cover, and tried to hit it lightly, and start laptop again. It worked!

Today I am again having same problem, but nothing is working.

Note:

- It's not even deteced in BIOS setting, so no Software issue here.
- It's been 100% reliable so far with no issues until yesterday
- My laptop SATA connector is fine. I tested it with another old SSD.
- I own a 1.5 TB 2.5" 7mm Hard disk drive.

I want to ask what is the issue, and how can I get it fixed? My most important concern is to get back all my data (into a new hard disk if required) ASAP.

Comment: Hitting your hard disk is one of the worst things you could have done. It sounds dead to me. Do a S.M.A.R.T check and if that comes back positive, replace the drive.

Comment: *It's been 100% reliable so far with no issues until yesterday* Everyone will die someday... *I want to ask what is the issue, and how can I get it fixed? My most important concern is to get back all my data* Connect your HDD with SATA and power cables long enough HDD to be outside the laptop. Ensure good cooling by air flow. Attach another HDD which will accept your data from old HDD. Start. If old HDD is accessible then copy your data quickly. HDD cooling to +10..+15 С (not less!!) before starting may help.

Comment: The drive is probably dead. If this data is crucial and not backed up, hire a professional to perform data recovery.